# Using Zener Diode for 12v input to Arduino

Tags: arduino, diodes, zener

The [MPGuino](http://ecomodder.com/wiki/index.php/MPGuino) uses a 5.1v zener diode to read an input from the switching of an injector.
[image: MPGuino circuit diagram]
According to my very basic understanding of how zener diodes work I used the formula:

$$ I_{diode} = \frac{U_{in} - U_{out}}{R} = \frac{14.51V - 5.1V}{50k\Omega} = 0.178 mA$$

which seemed far to low given that a [1N4733A](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/85816.pdf) is \$5.1V\$ at \$49mA\$. Would the circuit still work at these low levels, or would a smaller resistor be needed? And would the output from this be safe to feed in to an input pin on an Arduino? I hope this all makes sense and I haven't misunderstood how zener diodes work.

Answer (score 2):

Those zener diodes are clamps.

The circuit will still work at those currents, but the zener may only have 4.8V across it.  (see the dynamic impedance numbers in the datasheet).

Comment: So if I understand right, the zener is just there as a sort of backup/fail-safe to make sure the voltage is never higher than 5.1v?